# Is there a way to mass dump all wishlists?

Tags: wishlist

Is there a way to clear all items saved in all of your customers wishlists?  I want to clear invalid skus from being purchased.

Comment: Use MySql query: delete from wishlist;

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly, you want to delete all wishlist items associated with a particular user? ...

```
$customerId = 1; // Replace with the customer id you are targetting

$itemCollection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
    ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId);

foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
    $item->delete();
}
```

Comment: Is there a clear all?

Comment: No only the items from `$customerId`

Comment: so as per Fabian Said you did not worry of that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to delete all "wrong items" - in magento there is no possibility to purchase items which are out of stock or deactivated. So if the product is buyable, the people can buy it, if not, then not.

No need to worry about.

Comment: We have a non-saleable sku that people can add to a wishlist.  Once its in the wishlist an "add to cart" button appears for it.  Ive since removed the wishlist button from non-saleables but we are still getting those purchases.  I'm thinking those items were previously saved and people are checking out with them. Our store gives out a video view but offers the DVD for a fee. Our customers essentially are adding the view to the cart and expecting the disk. We just refund.

Comment: I don't understand. You have a product, which is what? Deactivated? removed? Never existed? And this was added to the wishlist? To the default magento wishlist? A wishlist item without product reference?

Comment: I should have prefaced this by I didnt build the store, only maintain it. :)

Comment: The company offers free informational videos to view online. There is a charge if you want a DVD copy. Both the item types were created as separate skus. Previously if the viewable video was added to the wishlist you could purchase it and only be charged for shipping. We never shipped a product just refunded and explained the error. Without redoing the catalog I just removed the wishlist button from the viewable video sku. I'm curious if an item was saved in the wishlist before I made the change could they still do this.

Comment: I believe with what I was given Ive resolved the issue but now need to clear the wishlists. However with wishlist data being in 3 spots I think it would be better for an intern to go to each customers wishlist and delete it via admin.

Comment: if you know the product id you could just delete the items in `wishlist_item` via query